# Get X,Y from LAT,LNG custom svg map

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, geo

Hi to all i'm developing a map with raphael.js as they do in here : http://raphaeljs.com/world/

the problem is that i'm using a custom svg world map so they function getXY() obviously wont return the correct x,y of a lat,lng.

How can i calculate the x and y of a given lat/lng knowing the map width/height and the rapport froma point and his coordinates (x:1104.73=lng:42.998604)(y:559.25=lat:9.424553).

they use this code:

`cx: lon * 2.6938 + 465.4`

y: lat * -2.6938 + 227.066

but i cant figure out what is 2.6938 and the other two numbers.
I've also used this math here:

`int x =  (int) ((MAP_WIDTH/360.0) * (180 + lon));`

int y =  (int) ((MAP_HEIGHT/180.0) * (90 - lat));

But i cant get it works,anibody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The formula to use depends on what projection (Equirectangular, Robinson, Miller, Lambert, Mercator, or other one) is used by your map. More on projections here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection

You will not find any help if you don't know what is the projection for your "custom svg world map"

Cheers

Comment: The projection is a Mercator, but anyway i discovered that there is no way yo do that.
So i started using D3 and topojson with provide u correct maps sizes etc.
Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Dtnand can you tell me how you do it ??