# geolocation on custom, non-Google map

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, geolocation

I have a "geolocation on a custom non-Google map image" question that relates to several recent questions/discussions on stackoverflow.com, but involves a different issue I'm hoping to get a little concrete help with.

Unlike `Dtnand` in [Get X,Y from LAT,LNG custom svg map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820406/get-x-y-from-lat-lng-custom-svg-map) and `Phpdna` in [Convert latitude/longitude to pixel coordinate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838915/convert-lat-lon-to-pixel-coordinate). I already have the geolocation latitude/longitude coordinates from the user's cell phone translated into x,y coordinates on my custom, non-Google map image (courtesy of [Trimaps](http://trimaps.com) custom JavaScript library).

What I need is a way to place a geolocation marker image (blue ball, red ball, whatever) on my custom, non-Google map at the x,y pixel coordinates calculated by Trimaps' JavaScript library. I'm a content guy, not a programmer, so I'm unsure where to turn on this.

Is there an existing JavaScript library that will accomplish what I want to do? The map is to be displayed on the Web. Thanks for your help...

Comment: There should be something in their (Trimaps) developer guide for this. Never used them. I went to their site and can't find one posted?

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in understanding that you have the x and y coordinates of the pixel you want to place and the marker to be placed there? Are you looking for a canvas or svg solution?

You're not really looking for a mapping libaray here but a graphics solution and I would suggest either starting to research the [HTML 5 canvas element](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) (which I think would suffice in this case) or look to implement a more complex solution with a library such as [d3](http://d3js.org).

Answer (score 0):

Am now prototyping a solution using LeafletJS and some JavaScript from heyman on GitHub at https://github.com/heyman/leaflet-usermarker. Will report back soon...